# Automatically app open while webview loads url while minimized application

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-webview

Application opens automatically from minimized state while webview loads url. How to resolve this?

Below is my code;

```
     webView.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
    webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)

            if (!isAdded) {
                return
            }

        }

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            if (!isAdded) {
                return
            }

            ll_progress.visibility = GONE

            val isReturnUrlFound = url?.startsWith(mStrReturnUrl) == true

            if (mStrReturnUrl.isNotEmpty() && isReturnUrlFound) {
                setToolbarTitle()
                activity.supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
            }


        }

    }

    webView.clearCache(true)
    webView.clearHistory()
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = false
    webView.loadUrl(mStrUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

how are you managing that activities state? Have you tried using an onPause() method???
Perhaps you can define how your app behaves whilst minimized and add an onResume() method to have it come to life again after the WEbViewloads the URL?
From my point of view and bear in mind that I am no expert in this area, your activity is not paused nor destroyed therefore it still shows up, you need to declare what happens to it whilst the URL is being loaded inside the webview. I believe that you can accomplish this with an onpause and onresume methods.
Let me know if that works, that a look at this link [https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-android/9781449362171/ch04.html#:~:text=The%20onPause()%20method%20runs,onResume()%20method%20gets%20called](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-android/9781449362171/ch04.html#:%7E:text=The%20onPause()%20method%20runs,onResume()%20method%20gets%20called).

Let me know if that helped. Have a nice day.